# ¿Cómo puedo crear un diseño de cuadrícula personalizado con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Hola soy nuevo en Javascript y tengo un problema con la creación de un GridLayout personalizado.

La idea es que el usuario pueda crear un GridLayout ingresando el número de filas y columnas,también que pueda seleccionar juntar los paneles que selecciona para que cree un nuevo div o panel y al momento de guardarlo se cree o modifique un css que contenga la información del grid.

Además, probé hacer lo anterior solo con Javascript y HTML pero no me ha funcionado, al crear más filas o columnas no puedo volver a seleccionar los paneles. A continuación dejo el código que llevo realizado:

```js
let filas = 0;
let columnas = 0;
let nombre_grilla = null;
let contenedor = null;
var foo = null;

function limpiardivpadre() {
  let div_hijos = Array.prototype.slice.call(
    document.getElementsByClassName('hijo'),
    0
  );
  for (element of div_hijos) element.remove();
}

function creardiv() {
  limpiardivpadre();
  let c = 1;
  let id_div;
  for (let x = 0; x < filas; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < columnas; y++) {
      let div = document.createElement('div');
      div.setAttribute('id', c);
      div.setAttribute('class', 'hijo');
      div.setAttribute('onmousedown', 'presionar(this);');
      contenedor.append(div);
      c++;
    }
  }
}

function agregarColumna() {
  contenedor = document.getElementById('grid-container');
  columnas = document.getElementById('columnas').value;
  filas = document.getElementById('filas').value;
  contenedor.style.gridTemplateColumns = 'repeat(' + columnas + ',1fr)';
  creardiv(filas, columnas);
}

function agregarFila() {
  contenedor = document.getElementById('grid-container');
  columnas = document.getElementById('columnas').value;
  filas = document.getElementById('filas').value;
  contenedor.style.gridTemplateRows = 'repeat(' + filas + ',1fr)';
  creardiv(filas, columnas);
  // seleccionar();
}

function seleccionar() {
  foo = new Selectables({
    elements: '.hijo',
    selectedClass: 'active',
    zone: '#grid-container',
  });
}

function presionar(elemento) {
  seleccionar();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  seleccionar();
});

function Selectables(opts) {
  'use strict';
  var defaults = {
    zone: '#grid-container', // ID of the element whith selectables.
    elements: '.hijo', //  items to be selectable .list-group, #id > .class,'htmlelement' - valid querySelectorAll
    selectedClass: 'active', // class name to apply to seleted items
    key: false, //'altKey,ctrlKey,metaKey,false  // activate using optional key
    moreUsing: 'shiftKey', //altKey,ctrlKey,metaKey   // add more to selection
    enabled: true, //false to .enable() at later time
    start: null, //  event on selection start
    stop: null, // event on selection end
    onSelect: null, // event fired on every item when selected.
    onDeselect: null, // event fired on every item when selected.
  };
  var extend = function extend(a, b) {
    for (var prop in b) {
      a[prop] = b[prop];
    }
    return a;
  };
  this.foreach = function (items, callback, scope) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(items) === '[object Object]') {
      for (var prop in items) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(items, prop)) {
          callback.call(scope, items[prop], prop, items);
        }
      }
    } else {
      for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
        callback.call(scope, items[i], i, items);
      }
    }
  };
  this.options = extend(defaults, opts || {});
  console.table(this.options);
  this.on = false;
  var self = this;
  this.enable = function () {
    if (this.on) {
      throw new Error(this.constructor.name + ' :: is alredy enabled');
      return;
    }
    this.zone = document.querySelector(this.options.zone);
    if (!this.zone) {
      throw new Error(
        this.constructor.name +
          ' :: no zone defined in options. Please use element with ID'
      );
    }
    this.items = document.querySelectorAll(
      this.options.zone + ' ' + this.options.elements
    );
    this.disable();
    this.zone.addEventListener('mousedown', self.rectOpen);
    this.on = true;
    return this;
  };
  this.disable = function () {
    this.zone.removeEventListener('mousedown', self.rectOpen);
    this.on = false;
    return this;
  };
  var offset = function (el) {
    var r = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      top: r.top + document.body.scrollTop,
      left: r.left + document.body.scrollLeft,
    };
  };
  this.suspend = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  };
  this.rectOpen = function (e) {
    self.options.start && self.options.start(e);
    if (self.options.key && !e[self.options.key]) {
      return;
    }
    document.body.classList.add('s-noselect');
    self.foreach(self.items, function (el) {
      el.addEventListener('click', self.suspend, true); //skip any clicks
      if (!e[self.options.moreUsing]) {
        el.classList.remove(self.options.selectedClass);
      }
    });
    self.ipos = [e.pageX, e.pageY];
    if (!rb()) {
      var gh = document.createElement('div');
      gh.id = 's-rectBox';
      gh.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
      gh.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
      document.body.appendChild(gh);
    }
    document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', self.rectDraw);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', self.select);
  };
  var rb = function () {
    return document.getElementById('s-rectBox');
  };
  var cross = function (a, b) {
    var aTop = offset(a).top,
      aLeft = offset(a).left,
      bTop = offset(b).top,
      bLeft = offset(b).left;
    return !(
      aTop + a.offsetHeight < bTop ||
      aTop > bTop + b.offsetHeight ||
      aLeft + a.offsetWidth < bLeft ||
      aLeft > bLeft + b.offsetWidth
    );
  };
  this.select = function (e) {
    var a = rb();
    if (!a) {
      return;
    }
    delete self.ipos;
    document.body.classList.remove('s-noselect');
    document.body.removeEventListener('mousemove', self.rectDraw);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', self.select);
    var s = self.options.selectedClass;
    self.foreach(self.items, function (el) {
      if (cross(a, el) === true) {
        if (el.classList.contains(s)) {
          el.classList.remove(s);
          self.options.onDeselect && self.options.onDeselect(el);
        } else {
          el.classList.add(s);
          self.options.onSelect && self.options.onSelect(el);
        }
      }
      setTimeout(function () {
        el.removeEventListener('click', self.suspend, true);
      }, 1);
    });
    a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
    self.options.stop && self.options.stop(e);
  };
  this.rectDraw = function (e) {
    var g = rb();
    if (!self.ipos || g === null) {
      return;
    }
    var tmp,
      x1 = self.ipos[0],
      y1 = self.ipos[1],
      x2 = e.pageX,
      y2 = e.pageY;
    if (x1 > x2) {
      (tmp = x2), (x2 = x1), (x1 = tmp);
    }
    if (y1 > y2) {
      (tmp = y2), (y2 = y1), (y1 = tmp);
    }
    (g.style.left = x1 + 'px'),
      (g.style.top = y1 + 'px'),
      (g.style.width = x2 - x1 + 'px'),
      (g.style.height = y2 - y1 + 'px');
  };
  this.options.selectables = this;
  if (this.options.enabled) {
    return this.enable();
  }
  return this;
}
```

```css
.s-noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#s-rectBox {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1090;
  border: 2px dashed #cbd3e3;
}

.zone {
  padding: 50px;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.padre {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.hijo {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#s-rectBox {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1090;
  border: 2px dashed #cbd3e3;
  border-radius: 0;
  cursor: move;
}

.active {
  background-color: rgb(45, 45, 146);
}

#objetos {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#btn_guardar_grilla {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="grid-container" class="padre">
      <div class="hijo"></div>
      <div class="hijo"></div>
      <div class="hijo"></div>
      <div class="hijo"></div>
      <div class="hijo"></div>
      <div class="hijo"></div>
      <div class="hijo"></div>
      <div class="hijo"></div>
      <div class="hijo"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="objetos">
      <label>Columnas</label>
      <input
        id="columnas"
        min="1"
        max="9"
        type="number"
        oninput="agregarColumna()"
        value="3"
      />
      <label>Filas</label>
      <input
        id="filas"
        min="1"
        max="9"
        type="number"
        oninput="agregarFila()"
        value="3"
      />
      <button id="btn_guardar_grilla" onclick="guardar()" disabled>
        Guardar
      </button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```